# Is there an English term for the concept of making grumpy noises like; "bah"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Swedish there's a word "fnysningar" which means "disaproved sniffs". I'm trying to think of a similar concept in English and I'm reminded of Christmas Carrol and Scrooge McDuck disapprovingly saying:

> Bah, humbug!

Is there a word for the concept of sounding out disapproval in this manner?

Comment: You might try the verb *grouse*.

Comment: [*Melchetting*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Daa8ZnxC-0Y).

Answer (score 6):

**Harrumph** is a vaguely onomatopoeic word that fits the definition of 'sounding out disapproval'. Here is the [entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harrumph) from Merriam Webster:

> *Harrumph* : to say (something) in a disapproving or complaining way—
>   used to suggest that the person who is speaking is very serious,
>   pompous, etc.
>
> [+ object] “These charges are absurd,” he harrumphed.
>
> [no object] They stood around harrumphing about the current state of
>   politics.

Answer (score 3):

"Bah, humbug!" he ...

- [growled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/growled)
- [grumbled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grumbled)
- [huffed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/huffed)
- [snarled](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snarled)
- [snorted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snorted) disapprovingly

Answer (score 0):

**Borak**: [1857. Notes and Queries, 7 S., iii., 
476. Poke borak, applied in Colonial 
conversation to the operations of a per- 
son who pours fictitious information into 
the ears of a credulous listener.](https://archive.org/stream/slangitsanalogue01farm/slangitsanalogue01farm_djvu.txt)

**Blague**:    [n.  humbug, claptrap.  [F]](http://koapp.narod.ru/english/diction/book5b.htm)

**Blat**:  v. i. To cry, as a calf or sheep; to bleat; to make a senseless noise; to talk inconsiderately. [Low] [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 0):

squawk - 1.say something in a loud, discordant tone.

1. Complain or protest about something.

the second meaning would suit it.

Answer (score 0):

There's [antithalian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antithalian) (Opposed to fun or festivity), but it does not really describe the sound itself (describes Scrooge himself to a tee though). Since it's an adjective, you can put it before 'noises' or 'sounds'.

> Scrooge makes antithalian noises.

---

Strepor: (Noun) Unpleasant noise/sound. I cannot find an online dictionary definition. Most dictionaries define the *adjective* form ([strepitous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strepitous)), but it is defined as noisy (as in loud). If you look for this word, you'll get a lot of references to Strep Throat. Perhaps there is a connection? *You sound bad when you have strep?* (This is speculation, so bear that in mind if you use this.)

Comment: More than a little obscure and likely not to be understood by the vast majority.

Comment: @Greybeard I usually focused on the more obscure words to help others expand their vocabulary, but ever since this site changed its core principles, I stopped contributing. Was wild seeing a notification.